# Valgrind program is crashing Bad permissions for mapped region at address

Tags: c++, memory-management, valgrind, memcheck

I am trying to run my program to check memory leaks in my program but whenever I start my program I am getting

```
==3476== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==3476== Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0xCFE3FF8
==3476==    at 0x005212e1: get_document_root (mongoose.c:1557)
==3476==


==3476== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3476== in use at exit: 2,134,492 bytes in 3,948 blocks
==3476== total heap usage: 5,473 allocs, 1,525 frees, 2,863,520 bytes allocated
==3476==
```

and in full valgrind log thee is no invalid read or write on the memory. 
I am not able to understand why it is crashing.

Comment: Did you try looking at line 1557 of mongoose.c ?

Comment: @Paul R that is line   root = next_option(conn->ctx->config[DOCUMENT_ROOT], document_root, NULL); from http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/downloads/detail?name=mongoose-3.0.tgz&can=2&q=

Comment: Great - should be an easy bug to fix then !

Comment: but nothing unexpected I found there.

Comment: Use a debugger - put a breakpoint at that line - look at the arguments being passed to next_option.

Comment: @PaulR thanks found the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was crashing because of custom 404 page and that file was not there. So it was infinitely looking for that file and doing buffer overflow.